# Capturing Inputs from Runtime.exec() in java leaves system in a hung state

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime.exec

I am trying to implement a program which can help me run Java, Python or C programs using Runtime.exec() in JAva. To limit the user from creating extraordinarily long outputs, I'm reading the input stream bit by bit and then appending it to a string buffer. My problem is, when I run a simple test case writing a program, which simply outputs a counter integer, as long as the buffer is not full, I get the output, but the program does not stop when it reaches the bufferCounter and hangs.

```
The InputReader Module

private String readCompilerOutput(InputStream inputStream) {

        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        StringBuffer strbuff = new StringBuffer();
        int ch = -1;
        try {
            ch = br.read();
            if(ch==-1)
                return null;
            int counter = 0;
            while (ch != -1 && counter < bufferCounter - 1) {
                strbuff.append(Character.toChars(ch));
                ch = br.read();
                counter++;
            }

        } catch (Throwable e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block

            result.setOutputErrorFlag(true);
            result.setOutputError("Oops! IO Exception");
        }

        if (ch != -1)
            strbuff.append(Character.toChars(ch));

        return strbuff.toString();

    }
```

The compile and Execute  module from which the input reader gets the IO Stream.

```
private CompiledResultImpl doExecute(String[] command) {
        try {
            rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            proc = rt.exec(command);
            String output = readCompilerOutput(proc.getInputStream());
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            if (exitVal != 0) {
                result.setOutputErrorFlag(true);
                result.setOutputError(readCompilerOutput(proc.getErrorStream()));
            }

            result.setOutputResult(output);



        } catch (Throwable t) {

            t.printStackTrace();
            result.setOutputErrorFlag(true);
            result.setOutputError(readCompilerOutput(proc.getErrorStream()));

        }

        return result;

    }

    private CompiledResultImpl doComplie(String[] command) {
        try {

            rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
            proc = rt.exec(command);
            String output = readCompilerOutput(proc.getInputStream());
            int exitVal = proc.waitFor();
            if (exitVal != 0) {
                result.setCompileErrorFlag(true);
                result.setCompileError(readCompilerOutput(proc.getErrorStream()));
            }
            result.setCompileResult(output);

        } 

        catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            result.setCompileErrorFlag(true);
            result.setCompileError(readCompilerOutput(proc.getErrorStream()));

        }



        return result;

    }
```

Finally the calling method

```
public CompiledResultImpl doRun(String snippetPath, int timeout) {

        String parm = "Solution";
        String javapath = "//apps//java/jdk1.7.0_80//bin//";
        String[] java_compile = { javapath + "javac", snippetPath + parm + ".java" };
        String[] java_execute = { javapath + "java","-cp", snippetPath, parm};
        CompiledResultImpl result;
        result = doComplie(java_compile);
        if (!result.isCompileErrorFlag())
            result = doExecute(java_execute);

        return result;
    }
```

The sample program this excecutes is as follows:

```
public class Solution{

public static void doPrint(){
 for(int i=0;i<50000;i++){
        System.out.println(i);

}

}


public static void main(String args[]){

                doPrint();
        }

}
```

The output that I get If I dont exceed the BufferCounter I have set...

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
27
28
29
30
31
32
33
34
35
36
37
38
39
40
.
.
.
.
.
4988
4989
4990
4991
4992
4993
4994
4995
4996
4997
4998
4999
```

Comment: 1) See also [When Runtime.exec() won't](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html) for many good tips on creating and handling a process correctly.  Then ignore it refers to `exec` and use a `ProcessBuilder` to create the process. Also break a `String arg` into `String[] args` to account for things like paths containing space characters. 2) Note that if there is an SDK available for compiling Java, there is also an option to use the [`JavaCompiler`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) from the standard API.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Have read the "won;t" article. I would have used the java compiler if i'd only want to complie java, but I also want to do pytho, .Net and c++. I'm trying to make a code challenge platform at work. Any suggestions on smarter ways of doing this.

Comment: *"Have read the "won;t" article."* The code seen above does not implement at least some of the things it recommends. What's the point of reading it, if you simply ignore the advice?